# delete request in nodejs and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, request

i have a list and i need to send requet for delete item in nodejs and mongo , but i have a problem with request .

for send delete request i use the module `method-override` .

when i send the request it show me this error :

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/course/<%- course._id %>?_method=DELETE">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                   <button type="submit">
                    <a

                    class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red"
                    ><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a
                  >
                   </button> 
</form>
```

and in the js file i config that :

```
        app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

but it show me this error :

```
Cannot DELETE /admin/course/5eeb5b6afa7d0081e93d56d6
```

and this the route for delete :

admin =>

```
router.use('/admin',adminAuthntication.Handler, adminRouter);
```

admin =>

```
router.use('/course',courseRouter);
```

course =>

```
router.delete('/:id', courseController.Delete);
```

**now whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used with full path at router and it works fine.

```
router.delete("/admin/course/:id", (request, response) => {
    const courseId = request.params.id;
```